# How do I get around 'invalid certificate'

Tags: gitahead

I am trying to clone a GitHub repository to my disk with GitAhead. In the left sidebar, I can see the remote repository. When I double click, GitAhead takes me to the "Remote repository URL" dialog, auto-filling the fields correctly. In the next dialog, "Repository Location", I choose the local directory, and click "Clone". I get this message:

> Failed to clone into '/home/[myname]/Development/[myproject]' - invalid certificate

What am I doing wrong?

[OS: Linux, openSUSE LEAP 15.2]

Answer (score 1):

I also got that error for an own created git repository (gitea server). The repo access is set up via https and an own created certificate (via gitea command). Such an own created certificate might also be your issue because if I change the https to http, everything worked fine.

I found an solution by reading the source code. Follow the instruction:

1. Open GitAhead
2. Open Menu Tools - Options
3. Open "Edit Config File..."
4. Add the section "[http]"
5. Below, add the item "sslVerify = false"

The file context from my installed GitAhead looks like this (a part of the file):

```
[http]
 sslVerify = false
```